# How to export Excel sheet from SQLite Database in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite, export-to-excel

so I'm developing this app which uses SQLite database and displays it in a TableLayout in android studio. Now I want a button to export the data in the TableLayout to an Excel sheet. I'm using this library to do it: https://github.com/androidmads/SQLite2XL

and my database doesn't have a name for it. This is my *DBHelper.java*:-

```
package com.kbjg.frissco.eattendence;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.PrimitiveIterator;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int VERSION = 2;

    //class table
    public static final String CLASS_TABLE_NAME = "CLASS_TABLE";
    public static final String C_ID = "_CID";
    public static final String CLASS_NAME_KEY = "CLASS_NAME";
    public static final String SUBJECT_NAME_KEY = "SUBJECT_NAME";

    private static final String CREATE_CLASS_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + CLASS_TABLE_NAME + "( " +
                    C_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
                    CLASS_NAME_KEY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    SUBJECT_NAME_KEY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    "UNIQUE (" + CLASS_NAME_KEY + "," + SUBJECT_NAME_KEY + ")" +
                    ");";

    private static final String DROP_CLASS_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CLASS_TABLE_NAME;
    private static final String SELECT_CLASS_TABLE = "SELECT * FROM " + CLASS_TABLE_NAME;

    //student table

    private static final String STUDENT_TABLE_NAME = "STUDENT_TABLE";
    public static final String S_ID = "_SID";
    public static final String STUDENT_NAME_KEY = "STUDENT_NAME";
    public static final String STUDENT_ROLL_KEY = "ROLL";

    private static final String CREATE_STUDENT_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + STUDENT_TABLE_NAME +
                    "( " +
                    S_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
                    C_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    STUDENT_NAME_KEY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    STUDENT_ROLL_KEY + " INTEGER, " +
                    " FOREIGN KEY ( " + C_ID + ") REFERENCES " + CLASS_TABLE_NAME + "(" + C_ID + ")" +
                    ");";

    private static final String DROP_STUDENT_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + STUDENT_TABLE_NAME;
    private static final String SELECT_STUDENT_TABLE = "SELECT * FROM " + STUDENT_TABLE_NAME;


    //STATUS TABLE

    private static final String STATUS_TABLE_NAME = "STATUS_TABLE";
    public static final String STATUS_ID = "_STATUS_ID";
    public static final String DATE_KEY = "STATUS_DATE";
    public static final String STATUS_KEY = "STATUS";

    private static final String CREATE_STATUS_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + STATUS_TABLE_NAME +
                    "(" +
                    STATUS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
                    S_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    C_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    DATE_KEY + " DATE NOT NULL, " +
                    STATUS_KEY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    " UNIQUE (" + S_ID + "," + DATE_KEY + ")," +
                    " FOREIGN KEY (" + S_ID + ") REFERENCES " + STUDENT_TABLE_NAME + "( " + S_ID + ")," +
                    " FOREIGN KEY (" + C_ID + ") REFERENCES " + CLASS_TABLE_NAME + "( " + C_ID + ")" +
                    ");";
    private static final String DROP_STATUS_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + STATUS_TABLE_NAME;
    private static final String SELECT_STATUS_TABLE = "SELECT * FROM " + STATUS_TABLE_NAME;


    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, "Attendance.db", null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CLASS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_STUDENT_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_STATUS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DROP_CLASS_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(DROP_STUDENT_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(DROP_STATUS_TABLE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long addClass(String className,String subjectName){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CLASS_NAME_KEY,className);
        values.put(SUBJECT_NAME_KEY,subjectName);

        return database.insert(CLASS_TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    }

    Cursor getClassTable(){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

        return database.rawQuery(SELECT_CLASS_TABLE,null);
    }

    int deleteClass(long cid){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return database.delete(CLASS_TABLE_NAME,C_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(cid)});
    }

    long updateClass(long cid,String className,String subjectName){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CLASS_NAME_KEY,className);
        values.put(SUBJECT_NAME_KEY,subjectName);

        return database.update(CLASS_TABLE_NAME,values,C_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(cid)});
    }

    long addStudent(long cid,int roll,String name){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(C_ID,cid);
        values.put(STUDENT_ROLL_KEY,roll);
        values.put(STUDENT_NAME_KEY,name);
        return database.insert(STUDENT_TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    }

    Cursor getStudentTable(long cid){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return database.query(STUDENT_TABLE_NAME,null,C_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(cid)},null,null,STUDENT_ROLL_KEY);
    }

    int deleteStudent(long sid){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return database.delete(STUDENT_TABLE_NAME,S_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(sid)});
    }

    long updateStudent(long sid,String name){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(STUDENT_NAME_KEY,name);
        return database.update(STUDENT_TABLE_NAME,values,S_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(sid)});
    }

    long addStatus(long sid,long cid, String date, String status){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(S_ID,sid);
        values.put(C_ID,cid);
        values.put(DATE_KEY,date);
        values.put(STATUS_KEY,status);
        return database.insert(STATUS_TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    }

    long updateStatus(long sid,String date,String status){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(STATUS_KEY,status);
        String whereClause = DATE_KEY +"='"+date+"' AND "+S_ID+"="+sid;
        return database.update(STATUS_TABLE_NAME,values,whereClause,null);
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    String getStatus(long sid, String date){
        String status=null;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String whereClause = DATE_KEY +"='"+date+"' AND "+S_ID+"="+sid;
        Cursor cursor = database.query(STATUS_TABLE_NAME,null,whereClause,null,null,null,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(STATUS_KEY));
        }
        return status;
    }

    Cursor getDistinctMonths(long cid){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return database.query(STATUS_TABLE_NAME,new String[]{DATE_KEY},C_ID+"="+cid,null,"substr("+DATE_KEY+",4,7)",null,null);//23.01.2022
    }
}
```

and this is the code I used to generate the Excel sheet:-

```
 csv_maker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                String directory_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Project Brown/";
                File file = new File(directory_path);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.mkdirs();
                }
                // Export SQLite DB as EXCEL FILE
                SQLiteToExcel sqliteToExcel = new SQLiteToExcel(getApplicationContext(), DBHelper.CLASS_NAME_KEY);
                sqliteToExcel.exportAllTables("users.xls", new SQLiteToExcel.ExportListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(String filePath) {
                        Toast.makeText(SheetActivity.this, "Excel Exported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Actually what happening is when I click the button a directory is created but the is not generated. Kindly help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where are you telling the exporter to use your directory? (Answer: Nowhere).

Comment: if (!file.exists()) {
                   IF ( ! file.mkdirs()) RETURN;
                }

Comment: No actually the app creates a new directory. It doesn't store in any existing directories

Comment: Repeat: `Where are you telling the exporter to use your directory?`

Comment: `actually the app creates a new directory. ` How do you know? As long as you do not check the return value of mkdirs()..